# Dynamic Server Side Rendering (SSR) and Client Side Rendering (CSR) in angular depending who requested

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering

Is It posible to create a Node.js service that renders the angular aplication depending in if is a client or a server?

Right now I am only using SSR, I followed this [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/universal) in order to create a service to render the app.

How can I use both rendering?

Comment: It's not the one OR the other. Normally angular apps are only rendered on the client through js in the browser. But if you add Angular Universal, the app is also rendered through NodeJS on the server. The only reason you add SSR is for SEO purposes, or to allow your app to be visited by people who disabled javascript in their browser. So after adding Angular Universal, you are using both...

Comment: I have understood that when you are using SSR with Angular Universal the whole requested page is render on the node js server.  This causes a lot of use of cloud resources so I was wondering if is there another way to use SSR for SEO and let the client render the page.

Comment: Perhaps you can wrap the ServerSideRendering middleware in another piece of middleware, which checks if the `User-Agent` header is `googlebot` or `bingbot`...

Comment: I wrote about this in my blog: https://blog.adnanebrahimi.com/how-to-switch-between-angular-ssr-or-csr-based-on-detecting-user-agent

Comment: @Adnan Very good explanation, thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind. I wrote it again as an answer @D.Pacheco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this [tutorial](https://blog.adnanebrahimi.com/how-to-switch-between-angular-ssr-or-csr-based-on-detecting-user-agent) to enable user-agent detection on the requests

TLDR:

Install the isbot package by `npm install isbot`

from `server.ts` change this line:

```
 // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });
```

To this:

```
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    if (isbot(req.headers['user-agent'])) {
      console.log('bot and running on SSR');
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
    } else {
      console.log('Running on CSR');
      res.sendFile(join(distFolder, `index.html`));
    }
  });
```

Comment: Nice! But do we need to run prerender before starting as your instruction?